# Symfony: var/cache/prod/pools is growing infinitely, what is causing this? How to avoid it?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, symfony-cache

I deployed a website running Symfony 4.4. This website has very low traffic, but run automatic tasks (commands) several times per hour. It uses Doctrine to connect to a MySQL 5.6 database.

After one day, the size of the `var/cache/prod/pools` directory has grown to 198M.

The problem is that the filesystem is slow with so many files, so removing the old files after a deployment take so much time that sometimes it fails.

The directory contains directories:

```bash
$ ls var/cache/prod/pools/NPSipMZaUK/0/
+  -  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
```

I looked at one file in a sub directory, it contains a Doctrine query and the mapping fields of the result. I see that an argument is written as is:

```
AND u0_.lastScan <= \'2022-06-13 23:21:52\'
```

So it looks like every query performed by Doctrine will create a file in this directory.

---

I don't have any specific configuration about Doctrine or the cache.

What process or configuration is creating the cache and all of these files? Are there options or alternatives to avoid creating all these files? The hosting provider (OVH) doesn't provide APCu or memcache.

The documentation about the cache doesn't mention this: https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/cache.html

---

Update: actually I was wrong, the project uses the [default configuration from recipes](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/main/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/1.6/config/packages/prod/doctrine.yaml) and it defines the filesystem for storing the pools. Here is the [documentation of the cache](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#caching-drivers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cache can be cleared by pruning it:

```bash
php bin/console cache:pool:prune
```

I will run this command automatically every day.

[Source](https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/components/cache/cache_pools.html#pruning-cache-items).

---

Update: in order to disable this cache, I used this configuration that use the memory instead of the disk:

```yaml
# config/packages/doctrine.yaml
when@prod:
    doctrine:
        orm:
            query_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.system_cache_pool
            result_cache_driver:
                type: pool
                pool: doctrine.result_cache_pool

    framework:
        cache:
            pools:
                doctrine.result_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.adapter.array
                doctrine.system_cache_pool:
                    adapter: cache.adapter.array
```

Comment: Have you an explanation ? I have different projects, only one  of them have a huge cache/prod/pool folder and I can't figure out why !

Comment: @Sami my understanding is that the default conf of Doctrine in Symfony uses a cache in the filesystem, check that end of this question. I updated my answer to show how to disable this cache (I use it on a small website so it has a limited impact).